# Почему возникает int 0h?

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

При выполнении в emu8086 следующего кода

```
.model small
.data 
.stack 100h
.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ax, 03B4h
    mov bx, 07b6h
    mov cx, 0032h
    mov dx, 0C4Fh

    div cx             

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h  
end start
```

возникает ошибка?

> divide error - overflow.
>    to manually process this error,
>    change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.

Используемое ПО: emu8086 v4.05

**Update**
Если заккоментировать строку `mov dx, 0C4Fh`, то всё работает без проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично - открываем любую документацию и [читаем](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#DIV)

```
беззнаковое деление. 

Алгоритм:

если операнд byte:
AL = AX / operand
AH = остаток (modulus)
если операнд word:
AX = (DX AX) / operand
DX = остаток (modulus)
```

так как `cx` - это word, то нам подходит второй случай

поэтому, получается `0C4F03B4h / 0032h = 0x3F0531` (`0x22` остаток).  `0x3F0531` никак не влазит в `AX` - вот и ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, потому, что DX:AX = 0C4F93B4h при делении на CX = 32h даёт 3F0812h, что при всём желании в AX не влезает...

Answer (score 0):

Если прочитать документацию к команде div, то имеем:

> При 16-битовом делителе (слово) используется 32-битовое делимое (**DX:AX**, причем **DX** содержит старшую знаковую часть, а **AX** - младшую). Команда деления помещает частное в регистр **AX**, а остаток в **DX**.

Причем там же написано, что прерывание **0h** генерируется при переполнении регистров результата (65536 для деления на слово и 255 для деления на байт) или при делении на 0.

А тут как раз переполнение получается