# Ошибка при знаковом делении

Tags: ассемблер

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть два файла: `first.cpp` и `second.asm`.
Проект пишу в эмуляторе 86 серии, но это не столь важно для контекста вопроса.

Итак, у меня есть весьма тривиальная на первый взгляд задачка - **вычислить выражение (22 / c + 3 * b) / (36 - a * c / 3)**.

В cpp файла происходит ввод переменных и дальнейший экспорт в ассемблеровский. Я смог написать код, который считает это выражение на cpp и на asm. Только проблема в том, что знаменатель у меня при больших числах выражается совсем не так и в сумме я получаю ошибку деления на ноль (это только в asm). а вот second.cpp считает всё без ошибок.

Итак, вот код конкретно расчёта знаменателя:

```
; Объявление переменных, которые экспортируются из cpp файла
Extrn num_a:byte, num_b:byte, num_c:byte, numerator:dword, denominator:word, result:word

; Вычисление числителя
...

; Вычисление знаменателя
mov al, num_a
imul  num_c
mov cl, 3
idiv cl ; Ошибка деления на ноль!
cbw
mov bx, 36
sub bx, ax
mov ax, bx
mov denominator, AX

; Получение финального результата
mov AX, word ptr numerator
mov DX, word ptr numerator+2
idiv denominator
mov result, AX
```

Допустим, когда я ввожу следующее:

```
a= - 100
b= -100
c= -100
```

Я получаю:

```
числитель= -300
знаменатель= -3297
cpp - 0
Divide error
```

Но при этом, когда я ввожу другие значения. Например:

```
a= -10
b= 7
c= -4
```

То всё работает верно, результаты совпадают. Что же не так?

Comment: Не деление на ноль, а integer overflow - целочисленное переполнение. По сути то же что и здесь: [Почему возникает int 0h?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639104/Почему-возникает-int-0h) - результат операций `(-100 * -100) // 3 = 3333` не уместится в регистре `al`, куда его пытается положить операция `idiv`. Выход - для деления использовать б**о**льшие  регистры.

Comment: @insolor, но ведь знаковое деление разбивает остаток от деления регистра в два регистра. Или я могу просто число в регистр dx записать, например, а потом сделать преобразование cbw и всё будет работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас происходит не ошибка деления на ноль, а целочисленное переполнение. Дело в том что при делении на однобайтовый регистр (в вашем случае `CL`) происходит деление `AX` на этот регистр, частное попадает в `AL`, остаток - в `AH`.

В вашем случае `(-100 * -100) / 3 = 3333 (остаток 1)`. Частное при всем желании не поместится в однобайтовом регистре.

Чтобы получить нужный результат, можно использовать деление на двухбайтовый регистр (`DX:AX / CX => AX (ост. DX)`):

```
; Вычисление знаменателя
mov al, num_a
imul  num_c
mov cx, 3
; Для правильного результата знакового деления, нужно DX заполнить знаковым битом от AX
mov dx, ax
sar dx, 15  ; арифметический (с учетом знака) сдвиг, DX остается заполненным знаковым битом
idiv cx  ; частное попадает в AX, остаток - в DX
mov bx, 36
sub bx, ax
mov ax, bx
mov denominator, AX
```